# Join the result of a left join to another table

Tags: linq, t-sql, join

I want to join the result of the query (that used left join) to another table. 
For example :

```
from c in customers
join o in orders.where(i=>i.qty !=0) 
on c.id equals o.customer_id
into gp 
from subgp in gp.DefaultIfEmpty()
join i in store_items
on subgrp.store_item_id equals i.item_id
into gp1
from subgp1 in gp1.DefaultIfempty()
select new
{
CustomerId = c.id,
CustomerName = c.Name,
ItemInOrder = subgrp1.ItemName
}
```

My problem is if a user does not have an order(ie cannot find an item in orders with Qty != 0), I get a null reference exception when I try to join "subgrp.store_item_id equals i.item_id". It isa saying subgrp is null.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that DefaultIfEmpty will actually return null for `subgrp`. I'd do something like this:

```
join i in store_items on (subgrp == null ? new int?() : subgrp.store_item_id) 
                         equals i.item_id 
     into gp1
```

Also, don't forget that `subgrp1.ItemName` can also have subgrp1 be null. So you have to do some checking there too, eg. `ItemInOrder = subgrp1 == null ? null : subgrp1.ItemName`.

However, overall, you're simply trying to use LINQ the same way you'd use SQL. This is possible, but quite unwieldy (also note that your query would probably work against a "real" database - the null references are really only there in LINQ-to-entities, SQL doesn't care).

For example, you could rewrite your whole query like so:

```
from c in customers
select new 
{
    CustomerId = c.id,
    CustomerName = c.Name,
    ItemsInOrder = 
      from o in c.Orders
      where o.qty != 0
      join i in store_items on o.store_item_id equals i.item_id
      select i
};
```

(of course, this is just a very simple example, you're probably going to have something more complicated, but the basic idea should be clear).

This may be harder to chew for some LINQ frameworks like LINQ2SQL or EntityFramework (but those have their own constructs to simplify stuff - you don't really need explicit joins anymore), but it's a much cleaner way of writing the query for LINQ2Entities.